# Javascript fails to get the value of a text input

Tags: javascript, html

My code below works if I manually set the value of `command`, but if I try to get the value dynamically the code stops working altogether. I isolated the line of code which seems to be the problem(comment after it saying it is where the error is).

If I comment the line `alert(document.getElementById("cdmTxt").value);` it works as intended.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<meta content="en-us" http-equiv="Content-Language" />
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<script type='text/javascript'>

function exec(){
    alert("hi");
    alert(document.getElementById("cdmTxt").value); //does not seem to execute???
    var command = "word";
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var txtToUpdate = document.getElementById("txtHint");
            txtToUpdate.innerHTML = txtToUpdate.innerHTML + xmlhttp.responseText + "<br/><br/>";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "HAS-sync.php?exec=" + command, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 141px; height: 390px">Managers<br /> DHTs</td>
        <td name="targetThing" style="height: 390px">
            <form onsubmit="exec();return false">
                <input id="cmdTxt" class="auto-style1" name="Text1" type="text">
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
            <br />
            <div id="txtHint" style="overflow: scroll; border:1px solid black;width:80%;height:80%"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: because your id is `cmdTxt` not `cdmTxt`. This should have caused an error on your console something like __trying to read property value of null__ or some similar message

Comment: you have a typo `cmd` vs `cdm`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo:

```
getElementById("cdmTxt") // It should be "cmdTxt"
```

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple! I rewrote that line multiple times too...

Thanks!